# run simple html or js file in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've created node folder and install the node server which is working just fine
I want to add to it some simple html file or js file and run it, what is the simplest way to do it ?

Thanks!

Comment: Use http://expressjs.com/?

Comment: I've express already installed, can you please provide example assume I've very simple file that i need to run what should I do ?

Comment: If you have installed express already then use that. Go to http://http://expressjs.com/ and read the Getting Started-> Installing and Getting Started->Hello World. Then keep reading  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either get nodemon through npm, and then in your terminal run `nodemon [your file here]` or you can use `node [your file here]`.

Nodemon is nice because it will restart your server when you change the files within it.